# Augmented Filtrations and Martingales in the Martingale Representation Theorem

Tags: finance, martingales, probability

*Note: This question is related to the following question about [complete markets in continuous time](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1616/complete-markets-in-continuous-time). In the linked question, the answer mentions that complete markets in this setting is a result of the Martingale Representation theorem.*

I'm trying to understand the statement of the theorem as given in [its Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_representation_theorem):

> Let $B_t$ be a Brownian motion on a standard filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathcal F_t, P)$, and let $\mathcal G_t$ be the augmentation of the filtration generated by $B$.
>   If $X$ is a square integrable random variable measurable with respect to $\mathcal G_\infty$ then there exists a predictable process $C$ which is adapted with respect to $\mathcal G_t$, such that
>   $$
> X = E[X] + \int_0^\infty C_s dB_s.
> $$
>   Consequently,
>   $$
> E[X \mid G_t] = E[X] + \int_0^t C_s dB_s.
> $$

In this definition, where is the relationship to Martingales? I see that it is assumed that $X$ is square integrable with respect to $\mathcal G_\infty$ and I assume that it has something to do with the fact that $\mathcal G_t$ is an "augmentation of the filtration generated by $b$." Also, what is an "augmentation of a filtration?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *augmentation of the filtration generated by $B$* is typically just called *the augmented filtration* and is defined using the below construction. It is more commonly referred to simply as *the standard Brownian filtration*.

- The collection $\mathcal{C}$ of all sets of probability $0$ in the sigma-field $\sigma\{B_{s} \: : \: s \leq t\}$
- The collection of null-sets, $\mathcal{N}$, of all $A$ such that $A \subset B$ for $B \in \mathcal{C}$. It is assumed $\mathbb{P}(A)=0$ for all such $A \in \mathcal{N}$.

Then the *augmented filtration* for Brownian motion to be the filtration given by $\{\mathcal{F}_{t}\}$, where for each $t$ we take $\mathcal{F}_{t}$ to be the smallest sigma-field containing $\sigma\{B_{s} \: : \: s \leq t\}$ and $\mathcal{N}$.

The point of this is to endow the filtration with some properties which are considered *helpful*.

The relationship to martingales is simply that $X_{t}:=\mathbb{E}(X\:|\:\mathcal{G}_{t})$ is a martingale.

Comment: Note that $X_t\equiv E[X|\mathcal{G}_t]$ being a martingale is equivalent to the law of iterated expectations: $E[X_{t+s}|\mathcal{G}_t]=E[E[X|\mathcal{G}_{t+s}]|\mathcal{G}_t]=E[X|\mathcal{G}_t]=X_t$